# Where could I ask such a question?

Tags: discussion

I'm affraid that this would be closed for "Distribution", but not sure. Given how dubbing simply degrades experience, I would find it very useful and this seems the best place to ask. Question:

"""
Title: Do european non-UK cinemas that play Star Wars 3D undubbed exist?

Background: I failed to find a cinema that would screen SW:TPM 3D release in original language (one closer than the UK*) so I didn't attend.

Checked cineamas in Berlin, Vienna and Budapest, but I couldn't find a single cinema that offered an undubbed version. This seemed very strange to me - do such cinemas exist? Other movies are screened in original language, why not TPM?

The motivation is twofold, obviously by the time of what will be left of the original trilogy I could book a visit.  (Actually I still would like to watch TPM, but cinemas won't even screen it any more in any language, afaik. :( )

But the other reason is that I find it very strange that it's this hard to find one for TPM and would like to know if they *exist at all*.

If not, was it explicitly probihited by the licensing, or all cinemas simply wasn't interested in doing it?

---

*: I live in Budapest and that would be obviously too far to go and watch TPM. :)
"""

Comment: Couldn't the OP just ask, where\what theaters in [Europe] can I watch movies in English?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a bad question for two reasons.

1. It's too localized.  You're looking for a list of specific places in
   the word in a somewhat specific region that are showing a specific
   title.  You're not liley to get an answer and the question is
   unlikely to ever help anyone.
2. It's too time sensitive (which I believe falls under too localized).  A threatre that's showing a movie this week might not be showing it next week, or ever again.

This type of question just isn't a good fit for a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: That's true. However, it could be detached into two or more separate questions, 1) whether Lucasfilm has a policy for star wars 3D that prevents non-English cinemas running it in English. 2) Why European cinemas choose not to screen such a high volume film in it's original form (assuming it's not probihited to do so). And 3) If not probihited, are there non-English cinemas that generally tend to screen mainstream ('Hollywood/expensive') films in original language? So what about it like this?

Comment: I cOuld see one and two floating, not sure about number three